# Expression matching each parameter inside delimited block

Tags: regex

In esoteric scripting language I have structures like those:

```
node % % % % % ... end
```

The '%' character represent an identifier, but let's leave it for now. All I want to do here is match every '%' and nothing more.

In text term: let's match every percent which is between 'node' and 'end' delimiters.

My guess was:

```
(?<=node )(?:(?<= )%)+(?= end)
```

But no, it only matches single '%' in

```
node % end
```

Any clues?

NOTE: The language is C#. So "\K" won't work. Important condition - I need pure matches, I can't use capture groups. It's a limitation of the parser, but if it can't be done without capture groups, I'll be forced to override built in parser and write my own, but I still hope it could be avoided somehow.

I need this expression to display hints for parameter numbers in editor. When you place mouse cursor over third expression in "node ... end" editor would show hint "P3". The real code would replace % with regex matching identifier "[^ ;\r\n]+", and the space with "[ ;\r\n]+". If it cannot be done in C# without using capture groups I'll just have to add a few lines of code to select ranges for hints manually. But it would be not as cool as single regex :)

Comment: What tool/language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to have the best performance ever I guess, but unless you can provide better constrains you will have to use 2 `.*` wildcards (make sure that `.` does not match new lines):

```
(?<=node.*)%(?=.*end)
```

---

**Edit:** according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind, .NET supports infinite repetition lookbehinds, even if the above regex is not a valid PCRE (it would cause the error *"Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed"* in other languages).

Comment: It takes a hacker to invent something like this! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like below to match all the `%` which is in between `node` and `end`

```
(?:node|(?<!^)\G)[^%]*\K%(?=.*?end)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC3uR4/11)

Comment: How do you know what language OP is using? That's a huge point when writing regex syntax like the above.

Comment: I forgot to mention (again). C#. And it looks bad, because it doesn't know "\K". I've even tried something with "\K" before.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the look behind `(?<= )`

the regex can be

```
(?<=node)( %)+(?= end)
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/jI6iP3/1

Comment: I'm afraid it's not it. It matches the spaces too, and captures groups. I need pure matches.